# Скачать файл .exe, через ChromeDriver

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день!

Использую Selenium CromeDriver. Появилась необходимость скачать файл с расширением 'exe' по клику на ссылке. Выводится предупреждение о возможном вредоносном файле и предлагается либо отменить, либо продолжить.

Вопрос: как избавиться от этого вопроса? Может есть какой-то аргумент? с которым необходимо запустить driver?

Пробовал и "--disable-web-security", и "--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection" и кучу других...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как это ни странно, но помог: "safebrowsing.enabled" в значении "true". При этом вопрос о безопасности не выводится и всё ОК!